# Want to search all marklogic documents with a particular value for a tag

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to search all the MarkLogic documents having "Sample" as the value for the element "tagname" with the attribute "attr" and the value "attr" using the Java API

```
<tagname attr="attr">Sample</tagname>
```

Comment: what is 'tag'? is it an element?  Please give an example sample of your content so the question is in full context.

Comment: @DavidEnnis Added the tag i am talking about

Answer (score 3):

With the Java API, you can use a [`containerQuery()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#containerQuery(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.ContainerIndex,%20com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition)) to match substructures contained within the element "tagname", and then use [`and()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#and(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition...)) with a [`value()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#value(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.TextIndex,%20java.lang.String...)) constraint for [`ElementAttribute`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#elementAttribute(com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.Element,%20com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.Attribute)) for the `tagname/@attr="attr"` and another `value()` constraint for the [`Element`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#element(javax.xml.namespace.QName)) `tagname` with the value "Sample".

```
// create the client
DatabaseClient client = 
    DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(host, port, user, password, authType);
// create a manager for searching
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();    
// create a query builder
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();

// build a search definition
StructuredQueryDefinition query = 
  qb.containerQuery(
    qb.element("tagname"),
    qb.and(
      qb.value(
        qb.elementAttribute(
          qb.element("tagname"),
          qb.attribute("attr")
        ),
        "attr"),
      qb.value(
        qb.element("tagname"),
        "Sample"
      )
    )
  );

// run the search
queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`cts:element-attribute-value-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-attribute-value-query).

You will want to wrap this in a `cts:search` and limit it. Depending on what you want you might have to "and" it with a element value query if you care about the value of the element and the attribute.

If you are going to be doing a lot of querying in MarkLogic you might want to check out the search developer guide at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev